# Different cell sizes in a Windows Forms TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

In Windows Forms, how do I make it so that the `TableLayoutPanel` will contain different cell sizes (either for rows and/or columns)?

For example: row 1 might have only 1 cell, row 2 might have 5, row 3 might have 5 again, but with different column sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot choose the number of columns per individual row, nor vice versa. What you can do, however, is to have controls on the `TableLayoutPanel` span across several cells in either direction.

Therefore, choose the required number of rows and columns & their sizes to set up the desired "grid" structure, then [set the `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171687%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on individual controls placed in the panel cells to combine these cells to larger ones. (These "foreign" properties get [attached by the panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx) to controls placed in its cells).

Comment: Link above was dead. Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-span-rows-and-columns-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 . To set RowSpan use: ```objTableLayoutPanel.SetRowSpan(objControlThatSpansRows, intNumberOfRowsToSpan);```